# Lookup site column created using powershell will have an empty source list

Tags: development, powershell, lookup-column, xml

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013 on-premise. and i run the following power-shell script to create a lookup column :-

```
#Create site column from XML string
$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML) 



$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://***/"
$web = $site.RootWeb


#Assign fieldXML variable with XML string for site column
$fieldXML = '<Field Type="Lookup" 
Name="testcol"
Description=""
DisplayName="test col"
StaticName="testcol"
Group="custom columns"
Hidden="FALSE"
Required="TRUE"
Sealed="FALSE"
ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInListSettings="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
List="Lists/dept" 
ShowField="Title">
</Field>'

#Output XML to console
write-host $fieldXML

#Create site column from XML string
$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML)
```

now the column was created successfully. but the `Get information from:` for the lookup column was emty, as follow:-
[image]

so can anyone adivce on this please?

Now i read this article 
http://innersharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/09/fixing-blank-lookup-columns-in.html
which propose a fix to this problem. so i run the following powershell script:-

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://***/"
$web = $site.RootWeb

$column = $web.Fields["test col"]
$lookupList = $web.Lists["dept"]
#Updating the column properties
$column.SchemaXml = $column.SchemaXml.Replace($column.LookupWebId.ToString(), $web.ID.ToString())
$column.SchemaXml = $column.SchemaXml.Replace($column.LookupList.ToString(), $lookupList.ID.ToString())
$column.Update()
write-host "Column properties have been updated"
$Web.Dispose()
```

now the site column have referenced the dept lookup list.. so can anyone advice if my above script is valid ? or i am doing things wrongly?